# Why error in Flask WTF "The CSRF session token is missing."?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am writing an application on Flask, I made authorization on flask-login, but an error appears during authorization itself. I use also Flask-WTF.

I have the simplest form of Flask WTF:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
email = StringField("Email: ", validators=[Email()])
password = PasswordField("Password: ", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=100)])
submit = SubmitField("Войти")
```

There is an HTML form:

```
<form action="/accounting" method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.email.label() }} {{ form.email() }}
    {{ form.password.label() }} {{ form.password() }}
    {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

I tried to specify the HTML form `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}`

There is also a function:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('/accounting')
form = LoginForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    email = request.form['email']
    user = UserModel.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if user is not None and user.check_password(request.form['password']):
        login_user(user)
        return redirect('/accounting')

return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

I couldn't find an answer on the Internet that fits my case, so I'm asking here.

Why does an error appear when submitting the form?

```
Bad Request
The CSRF session token is missing.
```

After rendering, the token is present:

```
<input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="IjhlMDBjMDhmYTIwOGUyNGQ5OGNiMTY0ZGZhOTU3Njc0ZDJhNjY4MDgi.YSW1_g.fhKQUYljjLKqUtl0OdcuOgJx02U">
```

I tried it both ways:

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY
app.secret_key = "ff82b98ef8727e388ea8bff063"
```

There are also such lines:

```
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
csrf.init_app(app)
```

Comment: try `{{ form.csrf_token() }}` instead of `{{ form.csrf_token }}`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the html template. remove the action and add the hidden tags

```
<form method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.email.label() }} {{ form.email() }}
    {{ form.password.label() }} {{ form.password() }}
    {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```